# Using pandoc converting a markdown document with LaTeX to HTML and LaTeX converted to SVG within HTML

Tags: html, latex, markdown, pandoc

Using pandoc, what is the command to process a Markdown document with LaTeX to HTML?

The LaTeX needs to be converted into SVG and placed inline with HTML.

Example:
Markdown content...

```
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \ \frac{x + \sin x}{x}
$$
```

The above is used in a markdown document, which needs to be converted using pandoc to an HTML document and the math to SVG.

I tried converting the above using `pandoc lwl-limits.md -f markdown -t html -o lwl-limits.html` but this is not converting the latex to svg though the page is converted to HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--webtex` option with a custom URL to get equations converted to SVG:

```
pandoc --webtex 'https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.latex?' ...
```

Images will be created on the fly by the codecogs web service whenever the resulting HTML document is opened in a browser. To download the images ahead of time and including the images directly, combine it with the `--self-contained` option.

Comment: Instead of webtex can we use MathJax, to convert LaTeX to SVG

Comment: @SantoshSKumar Not as easily, no. MathJax requires JavaScript to be executed, for which you'd need other tools than pandoc.

Comment: Understood. I am looking into 2 options:
1. Using https://hackage.haskell.org/package/latex-svg-pandoc which I haven't been able to figureout how to install and use it with pandoc.
2. MathJax released SVG support from 3.0. Trying to figure out if there is a way to use the new feature of MathJax